# Windows 7 Libraries best practices

Tags: windows-7, libraries

Windows 7 brought us some new features, like the Libraries that can link some file system folders together to one view.

I usually use a layout on my D:\ drive with folders like:

`D:\Downloads`
`D:\Games`
`D:\Movies`
`D:\Mp3`
`D:\Txt`

I'm so used to these names that I wouldn't like to change them - and here is where Libraries shine I guess.

What would be the best way to integrate this structure with the Libraries feature?

Comment: Please change your question into wiki  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't really say you need to use libraries if you only have one location - you probably just want to look at creating shortcuts on the left task bar.

The whole point of Libraries is to index multiple locations and write to one.

For example, if you have MP3's in 200 folders but only want to use d:\mp3 for new ones, you would create a library called MP3, set the 200 folders as the location of files (so you can search e.t.c.) but then just set d:\mp3 as the primary / default location.

Comment: So you basically just recommend not using libraries? :-)

Comment: I don't see a problem on using Libraries with just one location. Even if you put all games in the same folder, feel free to add a library for games.

Comment: Ditto to what djeidot said. I don't really think there is a problem doing this for one folder, however if you only do have one location - I would personally just use shortcuts. I use libraries for pictures and videos that are stored on two different NAS's (mapped drives), so I can index from one location - if I only had one location, I just think a shortcut is much simpler.